# How to decrypt the D.R.P. Mail Cypher message in Crysis-3?

Tags: crysis-3

I finished the game on normal difficulty, and noticed that somewhere along the way I picked up an encrypted message.  It appears under Story Information / Messages as "[ENCRYPTED]: D.R.P. Mail Cypher". When you read it, game controller key sequences are displayed that you must enter in quick succession, but I'm never able to get them all in time.  Is there any other way to decode this message?  Was it tied to something in the game that I missed?

Comment: Any single button prompts time out very quickly. You have a good bit of time for the 2 button prompts. So prioritize the singles when you see them then clean up the doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also just found this. some guy already solved

http://secure.mycrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=60665

Which says:

I used rot13 and hex decoder and it came out "Maximum Friendship"

Comment: Can you add the information from the link to your answer, please?  Saves people a click.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across it and managed to crack the encryption button sequence and was able to open the letter. From what I can tell it looks like another code to crack, but i have no idea where to start.

This is what I see on the screen as best approximated in this window:

```
______________________________________________________________________________
                                 CORRESPONDENCES
______________________________________________________________________________

D.R.P. Mail
______________________________________________________________________________

-D.R.P. Mail                                                                 1

 M6                                                                 10.10.2010
 _____________________________________________________________________________

 rot hex rev rot 120234655564 15 142565543502N584N565D4R4N5
```

Comment: What was the trick to cracking the button sequence?  Is it simply a matter of speed?  And do you enter them following the prompts left-to-right, top-down?

Answer (score 0):

I have the PS3 version of Crysis 3 .
I decrypted the drp mail by pressing the circle, square, triangle, and x buttons fast and randomly.
You'll get to a part were it will display a button sequence code that must be entered precisely in order.
This will unlock the drp mail
PLEASE someone write the PS3 code down. I found it can be used to unlock a  Nano-Decryption Minigame in the extras menu.
This video shows it being done for the PC version of the game.